# createMediaElementSource from an audio file input?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to make a website that quickly performs phase cancellation on stereo audio. When I found out about phase cancellation I thought it was amazing, so I wanted to see if it could be done quickly online to make it more fun [(Edit: it can)](http://mysterypancake.github.io/Remove-Center).

I found [this Web Audio API post](https://audiograins.com/blog/2014/04/karaoke-fun-with-the-web-audio-api/), which has an example doing exactly what I want (if you press the Karaoke button). However, it's a bit slow and it doesn't work with large files. [The author also mentions this](https://audiograins.com/blog/2014/04/karaoke-fun-with-the-web-audio-api-explained/):

> Really I should have used a mediaElement to manipulate the audio of a longer track, since we really shouldn’t be doing complex processing in javascript.

I tried to use a mediaElement, but I can't even figure out how to begin. I tried this:

```
<input type="file" id="upload" accept="audio/*">

<script>
    var upload = document.getElementById("upload");
    upload.addEventListener("change", function() {
        var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
        var source = context.createMediaElementSource(upload);
        console.log(source);
    });
</script>
```

I get the error `Failed to execute 'createMediaElementSource' on 'BaseAudioContext': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLMediaElement'.`

I know an input element is not the same as an audio element, so I can't understand how you could load it as a mediaElement.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`createMediaElementSource()` needs an `<audio>` element, so if we create an one and pass the file data to it, we get the source.

```js
upload.addEventListener("change", function() {
  fr = new FileReader();
  fr.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("upload").files[0]);
  fr.onload = e => {
    var audio = document.createElement('audio');
    audio.src = e.target.result;
    var context = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)(),
      source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    console.log(source);
  };
});
```

```html
<input id="upload" accept="audio/*" type="file">
```